# logcat displays nothing in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Logcat displays nothing in eclipse, but when i run `adb logcat` in terminal, thousands of information appeared. yes, logcat works well in the command line, but not with Eclipse. i have googled related questions online, but only to find how to open `logcat` in terminal, it helps me to some extent, but i want it to work in eclipse.

NOTE THAT: im sure i have selected the right devices in the DDMS view.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to select your process in the list on the left?

Comment: i have tried to select everything i can, but nothing help. @andreapier

Comment: I also have a same problem but select the tags to (Verbose, Info, Error,....) from the logcat and so it will refresh autometically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this ocurred with me too, i normaly use the logcat without eclipse try iit friend:

```
$ cd /"path to android folder"/android-sdk-linux/tools
$ ./ddms
```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps,

Go to Windows Menu,Select "Show View".

Now from the dialog box, Select Android and then select Device.

When it opens, Select Any Option from Device and imediately it will start showing Logcat information.

Comment: you mean open the device view? i have opened it, just as the photo displayed. but what's ***Select Any Option from Device***, i didnt see any option

Comment: Option means like a tree view kind of option, like in project we have packages, we can select package, like that in Device there will be few options, just select any of those opntion.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my dumb, i still cannot find ***option form device***, but the logcat works now, though i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the device then it will work for

```
go to Windows ->showview->other->Select Devices
```

Now select your device ex 5554 or 5556 etc

Answer (score 0):

The device/emulator whose logs you want to see is not selected in DDMS thats  why the logcat is not displaying any Logs. So select the device or emulator  from DDMS ,Just clicking on it loads the logs in LogCat.

What you need to do is : Go to DDMS in the left side of Eclipise. Then select the  device or the emulator,  then click Log cat view  .The logcat will be displaying the  logs-
If you can't see the  logcat prespective then:  Go to Window-->Show View-->Logcat